# C program that outputs if a number is divisble by 3 or not

Tags: c, loops

I am new to programming, and I have to make an assignment in C. I have to make a program that reads an integer n and outputs if it is divisible by 3. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use the % operator to check this. "A positive integer is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of all its digits is divisible by 3." So the program must add the digits of n, and if this is larger then 9, I have to add the digits of this number etc, until the sum of the digits is equal to or less then 9. Because then I am allowed to say whether n is divisible by 3 or not. I also have to print the number of the lose digits each time. For example: input:9999-----output:9999 -> 36 -> 9. YES.
I made a loop:

```
    while(n>9){
    lastDigit = n%10;
    sumDigits += lastDigit;
    n = (n-lastDigit)/10;
 }
    sumDigits = sumDigits + n; /*this is the sum of the digits*/
```

Now if this is larger then 9, I have to enter this number in the loop again, but I don't know how to do this. I made 3 other loops with if else statements, but that way my program is way to long. How can I make my program shorter? Because some numbers have to go through the loop multiple times.

Thanks.

Niek

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: `n = (n-lastDigit)/10;` Why the `-lastDigit` part? You only need to discard the last digit, that's simply accomplished by `n = n / 10`.

Comment: Funny that you are allowed to use `%` to get digits... To avoid this and simplify your life you can use `sprintf` to convert your number into string of digits.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Unfortunately I am only allowed to use the possibilities from C that I learned the past 2 weeks. This is just the basic stuff.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow. Yeah its weird. But my assignment said when the number is less than 9, you may conclude if it is divisible by 3, so if it is 9, 6 or 3.

Comment: Normally I just test if the interger form of the number equals the integer form of [the number / 3]

Comment: @EugeneSh. That would then require turning the strings back into integers which makes my lazy alarm go off.  instead, we can improve the original basic technique of grabbing the digits without using the modulo operator by just using `div()`.  And if we really wanted to be devious, we could use that function to test for divisibility by 3 on the whole number >:)

Comment: `n` is divisible by three iff `n/3*3 == n`.

Comment: Only one loop is needed for another solution: `while (n < -9 || 9 < n) n = n/10 + (n-n/10*10);`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been "deleted" by changing the text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two loops here - one that will loop as long as `n > 9` and another to loop over the digits of `n` and sum them:

```c
int origN = n;
while (n > 9) {
    int sum = 0;
    int tmp = n;
    while (tmp > 0) {
        int lastDigit = n % 10;
        sum += lastDigit;
        tmp /= 10;
    }
    n = sum;
} 

if (n == 3 || n == 6 || n == 9) {
    printf("%d is divisible by 3\n", origN);
} else {
    printf("%d is not divisible by 3\n", origN);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already figured I need a while loop within a while loop or something, but didn't know how. Your only mistake is that it needs to be: n = sum+tmp, instead of just n =  sum. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Per the problem statement, the input may be an integer, so you have to allow for negative values and zero.